# How can I use two where clauses in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, dql

So I'm learning SQL and trying to make a query with two 'where' clauses, one of them is just a simple WHERE status='error', and in addition I need to a add a second 'WHERE' but using also 'LIKE', my Query looks something like this:

```
SELECT sync.id
WHERE status='ERROR'
WHERE search LIKE '%sometext%'
```

But what I've been reading is that is not possible to do that, how can I use the two statements since both are required?

Comment: Use `AND` instead of using `WHERE` again

Comment: I would start with a `FROM` clause.

Comment: This site is awesome for beginners! Check it out: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp This one and the following page will give you exactly what you are looking for, but I recommend going thru the tutorial from the beginning

Comment: @Jackson w3schools is pretty crap. Do what everyone else does and follow the [MySQL Reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html)

Comment: See [mysqltutorial.org](http://mysqltutorial.org). It's really a nice place to learn sql.

Comment: Thank you guys, I'll follow the references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this way by using AND to make both conditions are required on the SELECT.

N.B: You missed the FROM clause

```
SELECT sync.id FROM table_name_goes_here
WHERE status='ERROR' AND
search LIKE '%sometext%'
```